# std::thread join() throws "std::system_error No such process" after joining with pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to simulate the `boost::thread`'s `timed_join` functionality (I know it's deprecated) with calling `pthread_timedjoin_np` on the `native_handle` of an `std::thread`. The problem is that despite `joinable()` returns true, the `join()` function throws.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    auto t = std::thread([]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});

        std::cout << "hello from thread\n";
    });

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    ts.tv_sec += 1;

    if (int s = pthread_timedjoin_np(t.native_handle(), nullptr, &ts); s != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "timed out: " << s << std::endl;
    }

    if(t.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "thread is joinable\n";
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works if the spawned `std::thread` is still running when the `pthread_timedjoin_np` gets called and timed outs of course. Why is this strange behaviour? Isn't it possible to "manipulate" `std::thread` through its native handle?

Comment: Anything to do with the `native_handle` would be completely implementation-defined behavior. It would be up to the standard library implementation whether it implements it in such a way that this works.

Comment: In the use case you have in mind, what happens when `pthread_timedjoin_np` times out? Do you log a warning and then terminate the thread or process anyway, or something else? Recovery from killing a thread that wouldn't terminate on its own may be rather non-trivial and leave process state invalid/corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

If you go behind `std::thread`'s back with `native_handle`, the standard library has no idea you've done this. Therefore, the result of `thread::joinable` is not reliable. Or more accurately, "implementation-defined". The implementation might check if the handle has been joined. Or it might not.

So if you intend to manipulate a thread outside of the standard library's control, you need to *commit* to it. The simplest way would be to have your `pthread_timedjoin_np` condition detach the `thread` object if it successfully joined.